# Author Access to Save and Edit a Document in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, acl, author

Is there a way for a user in Author access (and attributes Create documents, Read public documents, Write public documents Replicate or copy documents) to save and edit a document. The document has no authorized authors field.

Is this possible without having to edit the form's design?

Answer (score 3):

Author access means: The user can edit any document, that has an author field containing:

- One of his usernames (their may be multiple, if user has been renamed)
- One of the groups that he is member of (directly or via cascaded groups)
- A role that is assign to him in the ACL (directly or via group membership)

OR the documents have an Item "$PublicAccess" (but then everybody with "Write Public Documents" right can edit the documents, even readers having this right)

If there is NO author field, then the user cannot edit the document.

So there are two possibilities for you:

1. Fix the design of the database and add an author field (even adding a role [Public] and assign that role to anybody who uses the database would work)
2. Give the users Editor- Access. An editor can edit any document that he can see